# Batch reclassification in QGIS 3.10.2 produces error

Tags: qgis, batch, reclassify

I have a fairly long list of raster data that I need to reclassify. I was going through manual route but I found it too tedious to continue since I've to go through the same process if i need to change the reclassification range.So. I opted for batch processing function of grass r.reclass toolbox. But it continue to give the following error message.

```
Processing algorithm 1/10… 
Algorithm r.reclass starting…
Input parameters:
{'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META': '',
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT': '',
'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER': 0.0,
'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': None,
'input': 'D:/The/My '
'/Starting_Point_Geographical_Analysis/proximity_grid_lines_transmission/proximity_clipped_scaled_km.tif',
'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':D:/The/My /Starting_Point_Geographical_Analysis/reclassification/classified_transmission.tif, 'createOptions': {}}>,
'rules': 'D:\\The\\My '
'\\Starting_Point_Geographical_Analysis\\reclassification\\transmission_line.txt',
'txtrules': ''}

g.region n=0.0 s=0.0 e=0.0 w=0.0 res=100.0
r.reclass input=rast_5e31ba02638e53 rules="D:\The\My \Starting_Point_Geographical_Analysis\reclassification\transmission_line.txt" output=output40d1b0e389254015afa0cfc40267cd08 --overwrite
g.region raster=output40d1b0e389254015afa0cfc40267cd08
r.out.gdal -t -m input="output40d1b0e389254015afa0cfc40267cd08" output="D:\The\My \Starting_Point_Geographical_Analysis\reclassification\classified_transmission.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 431, in processAlgorithm
Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 400, in executeGrass
feedback.reportError(line.strip())
TypeError: reportError() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fatalError'

Algorithm r.reclass failed…
Execution failed after 1.36 seconds
```

[image: batch window]

after googling for some time, it appears to be a bug in qgis itself 
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33105 explains it in greater detail.

The solution appears to be merged in master branch of Qgis but the most recent version(stable, 3.10.2) doesn't implement it. How can I possibly solve it ?